# Magento 1.7.0.2 Too Many Redirects when installing magento with sample data

Tags: php, magento, installation

I m getting this error **"Too Many Redirects in the page"**
 during magento setup, between Configuration and Create Admin Account

**I have already installed sample data in a db called "magentodata"**

My php version is 5.3.8
MYSQL VERSION 5.5.16 (I am using phpmyadmin to install sample data)
Apache is 2.2.21
mod rewrite is on

**The error is hapenning only if SAMPLE DATA are installed in the db**
Anyone has a solution to this trouble?

Comment: Anyone knows something?

Comment: Want to know step by step of your installation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of http:// localhost/magento1702 try to use http://magento.local/magento1702
it seems like magento doesn't like base domains without dots

to have magento.local pointing to local server add the line
127.0.0.1       magento.local

to your hosts file

[windows]
c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
(open it as administrator)

[linux]
(not sure but seems to be)
/etc/hosts

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `local.xml` in `app/etc/local.xml`. When I tried to reinstall magento after loading the sample data I used another database. Magento tried to load the no longer existing database. Maybe you used wrong database credentials, too. Make sure you cleared `/var/cache`.

Comment: I will try it and I will come back to verify this!